# Regex to stop at first occurrence

Tags: regex, vb.net

So i have this text:

```
:40C:something1

something2

:42A: something3

something4

something5

:42B: something6

something7

:42C: somethin8

something9
```

I need to stop after the first occurrence of :42X: ... X being a letter (any letter)

So if i start from :42A: the text returned would be:

:42A: something3

something4

something5

But the thing is that :42B: could be not there, it could be :42C: so if after :42A: i don't have :42B: but i have :42C: it should stop at :42C:

So i need a pattern that starts from :42A: and stops after the first occurrence of :42X:
And it also need to be multiline because i didn't figured it out how to use multine in VB.NET so i use (.|\n)* as pattern

So far i tried this one but not worked:

```
(?<=:42A:)((.|\n)*)(?=:42.:)
```

But this one stops after the last occurrence, in this case is :42C: which is not correct

I am programming in UiPath Studio which uses VB.NET as language.

Comment: Regex is mot a processing engine, it's a pattern matching language.  I think you need to combine your Regex with a processing engine.  Something that can implement the sequencing rules you talk about.

Comment: I am using this kind of regex patterns from 2 months now, so it's working, i used it to a lot for similar situations ... but can't figured it out how to make this one.

Comment: The thing is that now it's maching all until the last occurrence, but i need to stop after the first occurence ... and i don't know how to do it ... i tried with "?" but not worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern `(?<=:42A:)((.|\n)*)(?=:42.:)` does not take anchors like `^` into account so there is no need to use multiline.

But using a pattern like `(.|\n)*` is not efficient as it alternates between any char and a newline and it matches too much as it is greedy.

Instead you could match `:42A:` from the start of the string and continue matching lines that don't start with `:42` followed by an uppercase char A-Z and :

```
^:42A:.*(?:\r?\n(?!:42[A-Z]).*)*
```

In separate parts

- `^` Start of string
- `:42A:.*` match `:42A:` followed by any char except a newline 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!:42[A-Z]:).*` Assert what is directly on the right is not 42 followed by an upppercase A-Z and :
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times

---

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9LLZ5A/1)

Note that the multiline flag in this case is enabled.